# What are some animation techniques used to drastically reduce the number of frames in a video?

Tags: anime-production

What are some animation techniques used to drastically reduce the number of frames in a video in the anime industry? I am thinking reducing the number of frames is the best way to drastically reduce production cost, so I am wondering what are some of the techniques used by the industry.

Comment: Possibly related: [What does it mean for animation to be done “on ones” or “on twos”?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/15567/2516)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean reducing the number of frames you have to draw, one method is that you can have a computer interpolate in between some of the frames. Most animation softwares have this feature, including free ones like Blender.

Another tip is to keep the background static and only reanimate the characters. Also, Partial Animation is a great technique to reduce how much you have to redraw. For example, if a character is speaking, only move the mouth, eyes, and maybe one or two body parts of that character, while keeping the other characters static until the speaker is finished talking. Most animation studios use Partial Animation. You can also reuse previously animated chunks of non-flashy things that people wouldn't notice, such as the waves flowing in the background of a beach scene or maybe the clouds blowing in the sky.